# How to drawing a line between two points

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2

In my app I have an `UIImageView` where I can draw inside of that.
How to draw a lines between two points in this way:
The user press inside the `UIImageView` and when leave the press the code create the lines between the first `CGPoint` and the last `CGPoint`.

This is the code I've used to let drawing (Inside a `touchesMoved` delegate):

```
    let touch = touches.first

    let currentPoint = touch!.locationInView(imageView)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
    self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width,self.imageView.frame.size.height))
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context,.Butt)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    lastPoint = currentPoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order of these two lines:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
```

Since you're not in a `drawRect` method, it is very likely that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `nil` initially, so you will be drawing to nothing.  After you begin an image context, `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` should return that context.